# How to return the value of a key if a given string matches the key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a dict and I want to use the string `"apple"` and return the corresponding values in the dictionary of every given letter in the string:

```
'dot-dash-dot-dash-dash-dot-dot-dash-dash-dot-dot-dash-dot-dot-dot'
```

```
morse_dict = {
    'a': 'dot-dash',
    'b': 'dash-dot-dot-dot',
    'c': 'dash-dot-dash-dot',
    'd': 'dash-dot-dot',
    'e': 'dot',
    'f': 'dot-dot-dash-dot',
    'g': 'dash-dash-dot',
    'h': 'dot-dot-dot-dot',
    'i': 'dot-dot',
    'j': 'dot-dash-dash-dash',
    'k': 'dash-dot-dash',
    'l': 'dot-dash-dot-dot',
    'm': 'dash-dash',
    'n': 'dash-dot',
    'o': 'dash-dash-dash',
    'p': 'dot-dash-dash-dot',
    'q': 'dash-dash-dot-dash',
    'r': 'dot-dash-dot',
    's': 'dot-dot-dot',
    't': 'dash',
    'u': 'dot-dot-dash',
    'v': 'dot-dot-dot-dash',
    'w': 'dot-dash-dash',
    'y': 'dash-dot-dash-dash',
    'z': 'dash-dash-dot-dot'
}

a = tuple("word")
for x in a:
    return("-".join([val for keys, val in morse_dict.items() if x in keys]))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Some things that seem wrong to me are: (1) you are using `return` outside a function (2) using `return` in a loop exits the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Simplifying with `print(' '.join([morse_dict[x] for x in a]))` probably does what you want.

Comment: Your code is not clear. Everything could be translated to `e` and `t`. This is why Morse code has defined pause lengths.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to explain what exactly you did wrong, because you seem to have made this unnecessarily complicated.

The answer to the title question,

> how to return the value of a key if a given string matches the key

is to use the fundamental feature of a dictionary, a key lookup:

```
>>> morse_dict = {'a': 'dot-dash', ...}
>>> morse_dict['a']
'dot-dash'
```

This will raise a `KeyError` exception if a key is not contained in the dictionary. To avoid this, you have two options:

1. check if the key is in the dictionary before trying to access it
2. use the `.get` method instead of the `[]` lookup, which allows to specify a default value which is returned in case the key does not exist.

I think in your case a default value would not be helpful, because what would be the morse code for an unknown letter? And if you choose to use an empty string `''` as default value, you would end up with a result containing `--`.

So, when using the first option, what you want to do can simply be written as:

```
'-'.join(morse_dict[letter] for letter in word if letter in morse_dict)
```

i.e., for each letter in the word, look up the corresponding morse code (which already consists of `dash` or `dot` joined by `-`), and join them all by `-`, and ignore letters for which there is no morse code.

Comment: If OP wants to preserve the "nothing there if letter doesn't exist" behavior, use `morse_dict.get(letter, '')` instead of `morse_dict[letter]`.  They might also want to use `letter.lower()` to allow uppercase too, so things like `word = "Bob's Donuts"` works fine too

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a list comprehension like this :

```py
a = "word"
morse_a = "-".join([morse_dict[letter] for letter in a])
```

Otherwise, I saw that you test the characters to determine if they are in `morse_dict`. A pythonic way to plan for unplanned characters could be with the method [`dict.get()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) :

```py
a = "word"
morse_letters = [morse_dict.get(letter, None)]  # Get dict values
morse_letters = tuple(filter(None, morse_letters))  # Filter None and cast into a tuple
morse_a = "-".join(morse_letters)  # Join everything
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below simple code with your given dictionary which is fulfilling your written requirement,

```
a = "word"
fin = []
for x in a.lower():
    if x in morse_dict.keys():
        fin.append(morse_dict[x])
    
print('-'.join(fin))
```

** Your can replace `print` with `return` as per your requirement in a function